# Почему создаётся объект не имеющий конструкторов вообще?

Tags: c++, классы, gcc

Почему можно создать создать объект с удаленным конструктором, если описание класса имеет такую форму:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass()=delete;
   int a;
};
MyClass a{1}; //все хорошо
```

А если класс имеет такую форму:

```
class MyClass
{
   int a;
public:
   MyClass()=delete;
};
MyClass a; //ошибка
```

То компилятор выбивает ошибку. 
Попробую предложить, что все дело тут в агрегатной инициализации, но неужели она может полностью заменить конструктор? Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Почему - можно? Нельзя ни тот, ни другой... См. https://ideone.com/TxjeM0

Comment: Приведите точный пример конструирования объекта без аргументов и ошибок. *А запрещается **только** конструктор **без** аргументов.*

Comment: Извиняюсь за неточный вопрос, сейчас отредактирую

Comment: @Harry, я говорю об этой ситуации - https://ideone.com/dCpDnF

Comment: Этот объект [нельзя создать](https://godbolt.org/z/soEa5n9zT). Может это вопрос по дефекту в старом стандарте, когда `= delete` не препятствовал агрегатной инициализации?

Comment: Посмотрите эту статью - https://habr.com/ru/post/438492/

Comment: @user7860670, вы попали в точку и выразили мои мысли:) Так что это за дефект?

Comment: Это дефект, что наличие удаленного пользовательского конструктора не препятствовало агрегатной инициализации.

Comment: @user7860670, вы так говорите как будто удаленный пользовательский конструктор является новым видом конструктора, разве то что он удален не означает его отсутствие?

Comment: Кстати еще похоже, что конструктор как-то нужен для агрегатной инициализации, так ли это?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поведение приведённого кода будет отличаться в зависимости от используемого стандарта языка. До C++20 удаление конструктора через `=delete` не отменяло возможности агрегатной инициализации. В C++20 это уже запрещено. По этому поводу имеется соответствующий документ [P1008R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf). Связанный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57430419/3240681) на enSO.