# Нужен ли тривиальный конструктор по умолчанию для агрегатной инициализации?

Tags: c++, ооп

Вообщем насколько я знаю, если в классе не определено пользовательских конструкторов и есть `public` поля, то для класса доступна агрегатная инициализация. Но если мы удаляем конструктор, тогда объекты [создать нельзя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1279576/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5?noredirect=1#comment2254579_1279576). Не значит ли это, что конструктор, определяемый компилятором как-то нужен для агрегатной инициализации? И является ли наличие конструктора обязательным для создания объекта?

Comment: такие вопросы следует задавать после ознакомления с доками https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо, но я так и не нашёл там ответа на свой вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Агрегатная инициализация не вызывает никакие конструкторы самого класса.

Сгенерированный конструктор по умолчанию не имеет к ней отношения. Вот пример инициализации класса, для которого он не был сгенерирован:

```
struct A {int &x;};
int y;
A a{y};
```